How plausible is the claim that Vulgar Latin spoken in the 7th century in modern-day Croatia differentiated between long and short 'a'?

U najstarijoj fazi kratki romanski samoglasnici mijenjali su se u slavenske po formuli i, e > i; e > e; u, o > u; a > a. Dugi romanski samoglasnici mijenjali su se u slavenske po formuli i, e > i; e > e; u > u, o > o; a > a. Tako je bilo do otprilike devetog stoljeća. Posuđenice iz tog doba slijedile su mijenu a > o jer se ona javljala i u praslavenskim riječima (*aka > *oko > hrv. oko; *bagu > *bogu > hrv. bog; lat. satanas > rom. satana > slav. *satanā > *sotonā > hrv. sotona), ali samo ako je taj /a/ bio kratak.
forum.hr, a web-forum

My translation:

In the earliest phase, short Romance vowels changed into the Slavic ones by the formula  i, e > i [front yer, usually denoted as *ь]; e > e; u, o > u [back yer, usually denoted as *ъ]; a > a [The sound usually denoted as *o]. Long Romance vowels changed into Slavic ones by the formula i, e > i; e > e [The sound known as yat, denoted as *ě.]; u > u [The sound known as yeri, denoted as *y.]; o > o [I have no idea what he means by that, the long 'o' was obviously borrowed as *y, as in Salona > Solin, Narona > Norin, Flanona > Plomin, Albona > Labin..., but that's irrelevant here.]; a > a. It was like that until around the 9th century. Loanwords from that time followed the change a > o because it happened in Proto-Slavic words as well (*aka > *oko > Croatian oko [a native Slavic word meaning "eye"]; *bagu > *bogu > Croatian bog [a loan-word from Iranian meaning "god"]; Latin satanas > Romance satana > Slavic *satana > *sotona > Croatian sotona), but only if that /a/ was short.

[You can see the context on my website, it is related to the second argument against my theory.]
So, how plausible is that assertion given what we know about Vulgar Latin?
As far as I understand it, it is highly implausible.
Vulgar Latin did make difference between long and short vowels, but it did so by the quality of the vowel, and not by the quantity (how long it is pronounced) of the vowel, and it did not make the difference between long and short /a/. That's why in no Romance language the 'a' develops differently depending on whether it was long or short in Classical Latin.
And that's why there were entire scientific papers written about how might it have happened that the Latin river names "Draus" and "Saus" changed into Croatian "Drava" and "Sava" (rather than *Drova and *Sova): you cannot simply assume the 'a' in "Draus" and "Saus" was long, because that would not solve the problem, as Vulgar Latin very early stopped differentiating between long and short 'a'.
Anyway, what do you guys here think?
